# Python Selenium WebDriverWait with EC.presence_of_element_located suddenly timing out despite no changes

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am yet again facing annoying problems because of Selenium. This time, tests that used to pass are no longer passing because of timeouts happening out of nowhere (or so it seems). I am using Python Selenium in a Django+Docker Compose project, and for tests the project uses a `selenium` container whose image is `selenium/standalone-firefox`. In `tests.py`, the driver for the Selenium tests is initialized as:

```
# WebDriver is imported as from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver
self.driver = WebDriver("http://selenium:4444/wd/hub", desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'firefox'})
```

In these tests, there are many lines of the form:

```
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "name_of_elem"))) # the wait time and the By vary, i.e. sometimes it is By.ID
```

These lines used to work fine, but now every single test that has this sort of line now fails. To make sure that I didn't change anything in my current development branch to cause this, I switched to the project's master branch, which was passing tests successfully just a few days ago. However, the same exact errors happen even on the main branch when testing locally. The project normally runs with a `docker-compose.yml` that excludes the `selenium` container (since the `selenium` container often caused failures with `docker-compose up`) and the tests are run with a `docker-compose-test.yml` that does include the container, which the `web` container links to (the `web` container runs the Django server).

Does anyone know why suddenly there would be timeouts? Increasing the wait times does nothing. Just to sanity-check, I opened up the web page after starting the server and manually verified that the elements didn't suddenly disappear. The elements that are looked for in the tests are still all there when running the server and using the webpage in a browser, but apparently Selenium can no longer find them in test runs. How on earth does this suddenly happen? I did a test run in Travis that was able to pass successfully (in Travis, the driver used is just Firefox() i.e. `from selenium.webdriver import Firefox` instead of `from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver` which is used for local testing); this makes me wonder if something about the image used for the `selenium` container has gone wrong all of a sudden.

One thing I've been trying that has also not been working is changing the driver to Chrome. So, for example, if I change the image for the `selenium` container to `selenium/standalone-chrome` and initialize the driver as below:

```
webdriverlocation = os.environ.get("SELENIUM_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR")
self.driver = WebDriver("http://" + str(webdriverlocation) + ":4444/wd/hub", desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'chrome'})
```

then I get this `WebDriverException`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/smaker/tests.py", line 574, in setUp
    self.driver = WebDriver("http://" + str(webdriverlocation) + ":4444/wd/hub", desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'chrome'})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 141, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 188, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

which doesn't make much sense to me, since I've already pulled the necessary image. The same thing happens if I leave the URL part as just `http://selenium:4444/wd/hub`.

Comment: could be so many things: from firefox version change to lost or incorrect focus. I would first try to see what selenium sees at the time of exception with `driver.page_source` - does it have the element you are expecting?

Comment: What do you mean by lost/incorrect focus? `driver.page_source` shows nothing from the web page I am trying to test but instead has a whole lot of stuff in `<!ENTITY>` tags about connection issues, i.e. connection interrupted, server not found, the address isn't valid, etc. Don't know if they're errors about my test or just all the possible error messages.